# Error: React Hook "useCallback" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Getting a build error usecallback hook called conditinally. if i dont use useCallback i get the error    JSX props should not use arrow functions

```
const LinkComp = <T extends {}>(props: LinkProps & T extends AnchorProps ? AnchorProps : ButtonProps) => {
    const {
        title,
        hideTitle,
        children,
        url = '',
        action,
        label,
        newWindow,
        className,
        iconName,
        isExternal,
        inheritColor = true,
        underlineOnHover = true,
        underline = false,
        theme = '',
        bold = false,
        onClick,
        modal = false,
        forceAnchorTag = false,
        appendQueryParams = true,
        showOutline = true,
        ...linkProps
    } = props;
    const [handleClick] = useRouter(action, url);
    const forwardedParams = useSelector(selectForwardedQueryParams);

    const linkContent = (
        <>
            {iconName && <Icon name={iconName} className='mr-3' />}
            {!hideTitle && (title || children)}
        </>
    );

    if (modal) {
        if (linkProps.modalTitle) delete linkProps.modalTitle;

        return (
            <button {...(anchorProps as ButtonProps)} role='link' onClick={onClick as ButtonProps['onClick']}>
                {linkContent}
            </button>
        );
    }

    // queryString.stringifyUrl combines the params from both url and forwarded params.
    // don't append the params for `tel` links
    const forwardedParamsUrl = queryString.stringifyUrl({ url, query: !url?.includes('tel:') && forwardedParams });

    const handleAnchorClick = useCallback((e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) =>  {
        if (handleClick) handleClick(e);
        
        return true;
    },[handleClick]);

    if (forceAnchorTag) {
        return (
            <a href={forwardedParamsUrl} {...(anchorProps as AnchorProps)} onClick={handleAnchorClick}>
                {linkContent}
            </a>
        );
    }
    // search extras uses the query params in a different way, so no need to append them here
    const fullUrl = appendQueryParams ? forwardedParamsUrl : url;

    return (
        <Link href={fullUrl} passHref={isExternal || newWindow}>
            <a {...(anchorProps as AnchorProps)} onClick={handleClick}>
                {linkContent}
            </a>
        </Link>
    );
};

export default LinkComp;
```

Comment: Can you please show all the code above the `useCallback` hook? As it is, that hook looks fine.

Comment: Is your `useCallback` defined inside some conditional logic?

Answer (score 4):

You need to move your `useCallback` definition to above the `if (model)` check. This `if` block may cause your component to render before the function has been memoized by `useCallback`.